# Why there are 2 'illegal start of type' error in my BinarySearch code?

Tags: java, binary-search

```
public class Solution {
    /*
     * @param nums: An integer array sorted in ascending order
     * @param target: An integer
     * @return: An integer
     */
    public int findPosition(int[] nums, int target) {
        // write your code here
        if (nums.length = 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int start = 0;
        int end = num.length - 1;
        int mid;

        while (start + 1 < end) {
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (nums[mid] == target) {
                end = mid;
            } else if (nums[mid] < target) {
                start = mid;
            } else if (nums[mid] > target) {
                end = mid;
            }
        }

        if (nums[start] == target) {
            return start;
        }
        if (nums[end] == target) {
            return end;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `return -1;` is outside the method.

Comment: `if (nums.length = 0)` - always true.  It is doing assignment, not comparision

Comment: `nums.length == 0`

Comment: @ScaryWombat not in any language that looks like this. The value of an assignment expression will be the value which was assigned, in this case `0`. In Java `0` is not convertible to a boolean. In less strongly typed language, it will be converted to boolean false.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to have errors like

```
if (nums.length = 0) {
        return -1;
    }
```

It should have benn

```
if (nums.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
```

Also

```
int end = num.length - 1;
```

Should have been

```
int end = nums.length - 1;
```

Your error less code would look like.

```
  public  int findPosition(int[] nums, int target) {
        // write your code here
        if (nums.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        int mid;

        while (start + 1 < end) {
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (nums[mid] == target) {
                end = mid;
            } else if (nums[mid] < target) {
                start = mid;
            } else if (nums[mid] > target) {
                end = mid;
            }
        }

        if (nums[start] == target) {
            return start;
        }
        if (nums[end] == target) {
            return end;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```